# Want to ask one thing about ask ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, community

I have joined this community very recently, what i got here is, people are not really here for help others, few of them are here for correcting grammar :) some of them are here for degrade others, i don't know why there is option for refuse or disenfranchisement in asked question section, means if you did't understand the question or you don't like the question,simply you don't answer that question., rather giving answer, people come and say irrelevant thing in comment section, i came here to learn and i got knowledge also but only thing i felt here is number of people in this community just degrade others, just because of that i would love to leave from here. Thanks

Comment: Topic is not worth much with at least a few examples. I can guarantee you that people abusing the site get banned

Comment: Your [this question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/828385/revisions) was edited by you almost 90+ times. Don't you think that's an abuse of the site?

Comment: Can you please explain why you made so many rollbacks?

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure what you mean. You posted a question and another user was nice enough to correct the grammar so that it's more understandable. That's great! It makes your question easier to understand so more likely to be answered. That isn't an attack on you in any way.

English is obviously not your native language so, naturally, you made some mistakes when writing your question. There's absolutely nothing wrong with that, we do not expect everyone who asks here to be a native English speaker and everyone makes mistakes when writing in a foreign language. However, our editing systems allows helpful users to improve posts and make them clearer.

Now, after that edit, for some reason you went on an editing spree and edited/rolled back edits more than 90 times! Wow! However, as far as I can tell, apart from the 2 users who corrected the language in the beginning, all the other edits were yours. So, two users edited to improve your post (2 edits) and then you subsequently edited it 97 more times!

As for the comments, I don't see any "irrelevant" comments there. All I see is people asking you for more details so *they* can help *you*. Basically, everything worked perfectly except the excessive roll backs.

Answer (score 7):

You don't seem to actually be bringing up any issue. You say we degrade new users, but you haven't even given a simple example, much less link, to support this claim. Without any examples, we just have to assume you have no case, and may be generalizing your experience to apply to everyone.

You may also be confusing the rather objective attitude of Stack Exchange with rudeness. Many online sites similar to ours tend to be more discussion-oriented (such as forums), and tend to have more relaxed rules. On Stack Exchange, we have a rule for almost everything; I think it's even a rule to enforce rules. If we don't have a predefined rule for something, then we discuss it on Meta.

That's where new users can get annoyed or feel abused. We will try to help, but only as long as the question is on topic for the specific site, and the person asking has put actual effort into their question and researching the issue beforehand. Trust me, we don't like to be rude, it's just that, seeing "how do I install Ubuntu?" three times in an hour can get annoying.

If it seems like users are being rude to you, flag their comments. One or more mods will come along and check the situation out. However, if someone says something negative about your question, don't take it as an insult. Step back and see how you might be able to improve your question, and see if it's even on topic for the site.

Comment: I couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 6):

You can find many places for discussing  Linux  and other subjects.  This part of Stack Exchange is very specific in nature.  It's our intention to be friendly and advise new users to use the site as it's designed.  You described "correcting grammar" as some of what our users do.

It's for questions and answers where people can benefit, not just the OP, but everyone.  If the question can be understood, but might not be formatted in a clear way, the users will edit the questions and edit the answers for clarity for the benefit of what this site is about.

If the question isn't on topic someone will advise the where to place the question/topic.

If you think someone is being rude, you can flag the post and ask a moderator to review it.

Please read site https://askubuntu.com/tour so that you can see what this site is about.  If it changed on a whim there are many dedicated users that would be affected trying to find what we already have here.  If you have a design of a different type of site for Stack Exchange, and there is enough people interested in the same, that is something that could actually be provided.

This question will most likely be closed because it doesn't meet the criteria of a clear issue with steps to reproduce where a definitive resolution can be provide.

By the way, open discussion and suggestions are permitted in http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com (the chat link at the bottom of the screen) and http://meta.askubuntu.com (Links under "HOT META POSTS" in top of the right panel to the right of where your question appears).

Answer (score 2):

I felt the same way on my first visit or 2 to AskUbuntu. The first time I asked a question it was off-topic, and some answers I offered were told to be not answers but just comments.

However after thinking about it a while, and getting used the the site and the way it is organised things got better. I think people seem a bit abrupt in the beginning but it gets better if you understand why they do it.

However, when editing or saying off-topic etc and you see the OP only has 1 or 2 points, make it a bit more tactful so they don't so easily get discouraged.